Cannot save captured image from webcam laravel 11 when using HTTPS
I am working on a project called "automatic face attendance system" that will detect users' faces, show information about the user, and save the captured image to a local server.
The process goes like this:
User scan using webcam -> system matching the scanned users face using models -> get the user data using JSON -> save the captured image to server using JSON.
The problem is, I've turned on SSL from Laragon and use HTTPS to improve the performance of my project, and everything is working except the function that "saves the captured image"
but, if I turn off SSL and use HTTP only, the "save the captured image" works properly, it will save the captured images to server storage.
here is the code:
async function saveImageToServer(imageBlob, label) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", imageBlob, "capturedImg.png");
    formData.append("label", label);

    try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/saveImage", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken,
            },
            body: formData,
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            if (data.imageUrl) {
                displayImageOnCanvas(data.imageUrl);
                console.log("Image saved and displayed on canvas");
            } else {
                console.error("Response did not contain imageUrl:", data);
            }
        } else {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            console.error("Failed to save image:", errorData);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error saving image:", error);
    }
}

controller
 public function storeImage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->input('label')) {
            $timestamp = getCurrentDate();
            Session::put('current_date', $timestamp);

            $image = $request->file('image');
            $kodePegawai = $request->input('label');

            // Ensure the upload directory exists
            $uploadDir = 'labels/' . $kodePegawai . '/capturedImg/';
            Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($uploadDir);

            $imageName = $kodePegawai . $timestamp . '.png';

            $path = $image->storeAs($uploadDir, $imageName, 'public');

            if ($path) {
                $imageUrl = asset('storage/' . $uploadDir . $imageName);
                return response()->json(['imageUrl' => $imageUrl]);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Backend failed to save image'], 500);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'No image or label received'], 400);
        }
    }

result:
POST https://xxxxxx.test/api/saveImage 419
saveImageToServer @ script.js:261
(anonymous) @ script.js:197
setInterval
startFaceDetection @ script.js:142
await in startFaceDetection
(anonymous) @ script.js:59Understand this error
script.js:282 Error saving image: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

I've tried many solutions from other threads, ask ChatGPT what's wrong. and all of their solutions don't work.
here is what I've tried:

check and update storage permission
validating CSRF token
use paths that have been specified on the server storage, etc


HTTPS is not about performance. However, when you turn on HTTPS, what is the error log?

the problem is that your server answered with html file. I don't know what exactly is, but it can be 404 not found page, or you got a php error at controller, or some security check with wrong token. Try to put try catch at php with logs, and double check your controller url, or server name. Check answer from controller at chrome developer tools -> network

@hassan Local.ERROR: Path cannot be empty {"exception":"[object] (ValueError(code: 0): Path cannot be empty at C:\laragon\www\******\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter.php:414)
[stacktrace]

@AlexNikulin No. Its not 404 not found. I have created a fixed value that will be sent by ajax to the controller. and the results are as expected. json sends the storage URL along with the file name, but NOT the image. I think there is a problem in the image capture function. However, when I tried other features related to the image capture function, there was no problem with that. the others run normally, not this one

@fufufafa please update your question with the full error trace, seems like the ssl cert path is invalid

@hassan no is not. i'm using ssl cert from laragon. please read my question carefully. i said when i run another function using camera and upload image, its work perfectly. this  function is using json to get and post the data. so its a bit different. but idk how it cant work
